# P element breaks apart when useing table in jquery form

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im currently having an odd problem. The problem is located at a dutch website so i will tell you what to click to find the actual bug :)

go to: http://welkommagazine.nl/luuk
Click on Nu Aanmelden in the top right corner.
Now you will see a slider.

The problem is in the first slide.
As you can see i use an image for a help option with a tooltip.

If I use a table or H4 tag for instance, the P element breaks apart as you see.
How ever i really need this to work. Already spent to much time on this.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You added a `p` tag to the question. Ha ha ha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is invalid to place a `block` level element such as `table` or `h4` inside a `p` tag.

See: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwelkommagazine.nl%2Fluuk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Amongst the many errors, you have this one:

> document type does not allow element
>   "table" here
>
> One possible cause for this message is
>   that you have attempted to put a
>   block-level element (such as "`<p>`" or
>   "`<table>`") inside an inline element
>   (such as "`<a`>", "`<span>`", or
>   "`<font>`").

The easiest way to fix this would be to change the `p` tag that must contain the `table` into a `div` instead. You're free to place a `table` inside a `div`.

You're using the selector `#steps form p`. You could change it to:

```
#steps form p, #steps form div
```

to include the new `div`, and you should be sorted.

Comment: Use a `div` tag instead of p and you should be OK.

Comment: It is also invalid to place a `<p>` inside of a `<span>`.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Good point, I forgot to mention that. Fortunately browsers won't munge the DOM by splitting the `span` up like they're doing with `p` tags in this instance.

Comment: Ok, that was kind off stupid on my side :) I knew it isn't allowed, but ignored it :( thanks for your help and I think it will fix it so i will mark this as correct answer.